# Show tblproperties command in Hive gives incorrect results

Tags: sql, hive

When I run `show tblproperties sometblname`, I get:

- numRows = -1
- rawDataSize = -1
- totalSize = 0
- COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE = false

But my table has data in it. Is there a reason tblproperties shows something different?

Comment: is this external table or managed table ? have to set any properties while creating the table ?

Comment: This was created as an external table. I didn't have to set any properties while creating

Answer (score 1):

Just run `ANALYSE TABLE`, syntax:

```
ANALYZE TABLE [db_name.]tablename [PARTITION(partcol1[=val1], partcol2[=val2], ...)]
  COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  [FOR COLUMNS]          -- (Note: Hive 0.10.0 and later.)
  [CACHE METADATA]       -- (Note: Hive 2.1.0 and later.)
  [NOSCAN];
```

When the user issues that command but doesn't specify any partition specs, statistics are gathered for the table as well as all the partitions (if any).

Refer: [Existing Tables – ANALYZE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev#StatsDev-ExistingTables%E2%80%93ANALYZE)